# FullCalendar Context Menu

Tags: html, css, reactjs, fullcalendar, contextmenu

I'm trying to use a tiny [context menu library](https://dgoguerra.github.io/bootstrap-menu/demos.html), to provide context menu to events, however, the menu position always shows off in the bottom corner instead of by the event were "right-click" took place.

[image: Here is an example]

In this example, I have tried using FullCalendar with React component, I have also tried using vanilla javascript version and got the same issue.

Here is my sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-react-7nggi?fontsize=14

Any ideas on how I can go about fixing such issue?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue with a workaround, by taking the coordinates of right-click event and re-position the menu accordingly.

```
$('.fc-event').on('contextmenu', function (e) {
  $('.bootstrapMenu').offset({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX })
});
```